# Sony SpresenseでGPSの取得がうまくいきません。

Tags: spresense

Arduino IDEのスケッチ例でgnssを使用した場合、以下のような警告文が表示され、うまく位置情報を取得することができません。

[警告文]

```
cxd56_farapiinitialize: Mismatched version: loader(170765) != Self(17594)
cxd56_farapiinitialize: Please update and gnssfw firmwares!!
```

そのほかのプログラムは動作することができます。
何を更新すれば良いのか教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 1):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

お問い合わせの警告文についてお答えいたします。
ご提示いただいたシリアルログの文章を確認する限りでは、お使いのSpresense Arduino Library
で必要とされているブートローダよりも古いものがSpresenseにインストールされているようです。
そして、それが位置測位ができない要因となっております。

お手数ですが、Spresense Arduino Libraryを**v1.2.0**に更新頂き、ブートローダを更新してください。
ブートローダ更新方法については以下の通りになります。

1. Spresenseをお使いのPCに接続します
2. "ツール"→"シリアルポート" を辿っていただき、Spresenseのシリアルポートを選択します。(Spresenseと表記されています。)
3. "ツール"メニューの中の"ブートローダを書き込む"を選択します。
4. End-User License Agreementの同意にチェックを入れ、OKボタンをクリックします。
5. ご使用いただいているスケッチ例 `gnss` を再度ロードします。

これらの手順を実施頂くことでブートローダの更新を行うことができます。
より詳細な説明は次のページにありますので是非ご覧ください。
→[2.2. Spresenseローダーのインストール](https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/developer-tools/get-started-using-arduino-ide/set-up-the-arduino-ide#_spresense%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%80%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB)

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

SPRESENSEサポートチーム

Comment: 丁寧な説明ありがとうございます。
上記の通り行ったところ、無事に解決することができました。

Answer (score 0):

英語ですが、　[Sony Spresense Board Review with NuttX based Spresense SDK](https://www.cnx-software.com/2019/01/06/sony-spresense-review-nuttx-spresense-sdk/)　の記事が参考になるのでは？